# Different styles of footnote numbering with beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, footnotes

I am writing a presentation in beamer and I use footnotes for references, making use of the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` commands. When I use these in `block`, the numberings of marks and texts is different. I mean the marks are numbered using Arabic numerals (1,2,...) but the texts are numbered using small letters (a,b,...). Here is an image to illustrate this issue:
[image]
The corresponding source is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Sample frame}
    \begin{block}{Sample block}
      Some text\footnotemark[1]
      \footnotetext[1]{Footnote}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to solve this inconsistency and unify both numberings?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @m0nhawk Sorry, forgot about that one...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the regular `\footnote` mechanism. If you want to have the footnote at the bottom of the frame then you can include `[frame]` option. Note that `beamer` overwrites almost all the footnote mechanisms from scratch. Hence better not expect consistent behavior with other packages.

In fact omit footnotes if possible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Sample frame}
    \begin{block}{Sample block}
      Some text\footnote{Footnote}. Some other text\footnote[frame]{Another footnote}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know that it is not recommended to use footnotes in beamer but I find them useful for references. So far, I did not find a better generally applicable way how to include them.